# Create a button which creates button

Tags: c#, .net, button

I am a begginer in C# and I want to create a button which creates button. 
but these buttons never appear...

please find my code :

```
    private void addstrat3_i_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel3strat.Width += 200;
        Button addstrat3_2 = new Button();
        addstrat3_2.Size = new Size(210, 41);
        addstrat3_2.Location = new Point(50,50);
        addstrat3_2.Visible = true; 
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

You have to add the button (or any other controls) on the form using the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property, for sample:

```
private void addstrat3_i_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3strat.Width += 200;
    Button addstrat3_2 = new Button();
    addstrat3_2.Size = new Size(210, 41);
    addstrat3_2.Location = new Point(50,50);
    addstrat3_2.Visible = true; 

    // add control
    this.Controls.Add(addstrat3_2);    
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just beat me to it!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the button to the form.

```
this.Controls.Add(addstrat3_2);
```